# Using close button in C#

Tags: c#, windows

I'm building an app in C# using VS 2008 - I've added a method of checking if a file has changed when it is closed, but this only works for the File>close menu. Is there any way to get the red X in the top right to actually do anything before shutting everything? If so, how? I've only been doing C# for a few days, and this is incredibly confusing - there are no methods for the overall interface window anywhere. Help is much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the Form.FormClosing event. Or the FormClosed event, that comes later and cannot cancel the closng.

And from the File|Close menuItem, just Close() the Form.

If you do that, you have 1 spot (FormClosing) where all the possible ways of closing a Form (including ALT+F4 and TaskManager) converge.

Do take a look at e.CloseReason, you don't want to be in the way when it is for example `WindowsShutDown`

Comment: When using these events you have to take into account the fact that on OK or Cancel buttons ( any Dialog closing Button for that matter) those events get called as well, so the code in your event handler will have to take those situations into consideration.

Comment: @Anton, correct, but from File|Closing i gathered that this was not a Dialog.

Comment: tbh my assumption may be completely premature, I just added this to (hopefully) save the OP some work  just in case :)

Answer (score 3):

You could probably do it through the window's closing event: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.closing.aspx